# Flutter pass String with callback

Tags: flutter, dart

this is simple code to show widget with overlay support and in `onReplay` of that i want to get string as message to show that with for example `toast`

```
showOverlayNotification((context) {
  return MessageNotification(
    message: messages[3],
    onReplay: (message) {
      OverlaySupportEntry.of(context).dismiss();
      toast(message);
    },
  );
}, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 4000));
```

my implemented code to pass message as string is not correct and i get

> error: The final variable 'onReply' must be initialized.

how can i resolve this problem?

```
typedef StringToVoidFunc = void Function(String);
const messages = [
  ...
];

class MessageNotification extends StatelessWidget {
  //final VoidCallback onReplay;
  final StringToVoidFunc onReply;
  final String message;

  const MessageNotification({
    Key key,
    this.onReplay,
    @required this.message,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          if (onReplay != null) onReplay("sample pass message");
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'ssss',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 26.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done the mistake in the type error

Change this

```
final StringToVoidFunc onReply;
```

**to**

```
final StringToVoidFunc onReplay;
```

error resolved.